# BootStrap Nav bar reloading on every nav click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a twitter bootstrap nav bar, but evertime I navigate on a link it is clearly reloading the navbar with everything else. Isn't it not supposed to do that? I would like it if it didn't. I'm not sure maybe if I'm doing something wrong in my _Layout or not. Any ideas on why my navbar could be reloading?

```
            <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dt-min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="../../Content/Reflection.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="float-left" style="width:315px">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Kinfolk", "Index", "Home", new { @style = "color:Orange" })</p>
            </div>

            <div class="float-center">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>

                    <ul id="menu" class="nav">

                        <li>
                         <div class="reflection">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("AllWallPost", "Home")" title="Home">
                            <img src="../../Images/home (1).ico" />
                        </a>  
                         </div>                        
                        </li>  

                        <li>
                         <div class="reflection">
                         <a href="@Url.Action("UserProfile", "UserProfile")" title="My Profile">
                         <img src="../../Images/user.ico" />
                         </a>                           
                         </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                         <div class="reflection">
                         <a href="#" title="Events">
                         <img src="../../Images/calendar_2.ico" />
                         </a>                           
                         </div>
                        </li>


                       </li>
                    </ul>

                </nav>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <ul id="social">
                    <li><a href="http://facebook.com" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://twitter.com" class="twitter">Twitter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>                            
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided, it is normal that the page reloads when you click on a link.

If you want the page to change without reloading everything, you'll have to use some Ajax (JavaScript) and a combination of `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` (controller) and `PartialView` (view).

There are lots of resources out there with those keywords.

Comment: As far as performance goes or anything at that. Is this important that I should configure my code to stop the nav bar from reloading or is it ok that everything reloads? Thx for reply also.

Comment: Actually, I just realized, the navbar is reloading for chrome but not for IE, go figure. No idea why.

Comment: @TMan No, you are just seeing the flash of page loading for chrome, but it reloads for both. I'd say that it's ok for now, don't worry about performance.